# My Validation of TextFormField Form using flutter is not working?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

This part of the project is for the feedback page.

I am building this part in our project I manage to connect it to Firestore but the validation is not working I read the flutter docs to no avail I did not manage to make it work. Do I really need a global key? Is my code to connect to Firestore wrong?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SimpleDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  final title;
  const SimpleDialog(this.title, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Alert'),
      content: Text(title),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: const Text('OK'))
      ],
    );
  }
}

class FeedbackPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FeedbackPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<FeedbackPage> createState() => _FeedbackPageState();
}

class _FeedbackPageState extends State<FeedbackPage> {
  final nameOfuser = TextEditingController();
  final emailOfuser = TextEditingController();
  final messageOfuser = TextEditingController();
  

  List<bool> isTypeSelected = [false, false, false, true, true];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        // AppBar para sa taas ng design
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            "PicLeaf",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 102, 1.0),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          shadowColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 95, 94, 94),
        ),

        //body of the application
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffeeeeee),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              const Text(
                "Feedback",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30.0,
                    fontFamily: 'RobotoBold',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 102, 1.0)),
              ),
              const Text(
                "Give us your feedback!",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium',
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: nameOfuser,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        hintText: "Name",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                      validator: (nameOfuser) {
                        if (nameOfuser == null || nameOfuser.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your Name';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: emailOfuser,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        hintText: "Email",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                      validator: (emailOfuser) {
                        if (emailOfuser == null || emailOfuser.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your Email';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: messageOfuser,
                      maxLines: 6,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        hintText: "Message",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                      validator: (messageOfuser) {
                        if (messageOfuser == null || messageOfuser.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter your Message';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                    MaterialButton(
                      height: 50.0,
                      minWidth: double.infinity,
                      color: const Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 102, 1.0),
                      onPressed: () {
                        showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return const SimpleDialog('Feedback Submitted');
                            });
                        Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                          "Name": nameOfuser.text,
                          "Email": emailOfuser.text,
                          "Message": messageOfuser.text,
                          "Time": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                        };
                        setState(() {
                          nameOfuser.clear();
                          emailOfuser.clear();
                          messageOfuser.clear();
                        });
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection("FeedbackMessages")
                            .add(data);
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        "SUBMIT",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'RobotoBold',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 10),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Contact Us!',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontFamily: 'RobotoBold',
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 102, 1.0)),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                          child: TextButton.icon(
                            // <-- TextButton
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.facebook,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              size: 35.0,
                            ),
                            label: const Text(
                              'facebook.com/picleaf',
                              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium'),
                            ),
                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                              foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 10),
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                            child: TextButton.icon(
                              // <-- TextButton
                              onPressed: () {},
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.email,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                size: 35.0,
                              ),

                              label: const Text(
                                'picleaf@gmail.com',
                                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium'),
                              ),

                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            )),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  wrap with `Form` widget to validate it and use a Global key to validate it.

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

```dart
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
  child: Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
```

You can also pass the key using `FeedbackPage` constructor.

And check like

```dart
final bool isValdded = _formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false;
if (isValdded) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    const SnackBar(content: Text(' valid')),
  );
}
```

You can find more about [/validation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation)

Answer (score 0):

First you need `Form` widget, so wrap your padding with one second you need pass it `GlobalKey<FormState>`, so define one like this:

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

then do this:

```
Form(
  key: _formKey
  child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                 ....
)
```

lastly on your Submit button do this:

```
MaterialButton(
      height: 50.0,
      minWidth: double.infinity,
      color: const Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 102, 1.0),
      onPressed:  _formKey.currentState != null &&
                          _formKey.currentState.validate()
                      ?() {
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return const SimpleDialog('Feedback Submitted');
                        });
                    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                      "Name": nameOfuser.text,
                      "Email": emailOfuser.text,
                      "Message": messageOfuser.text,
                      "Time": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                    };
                    setState(() {
                      nameOfuser.clear();
                      emailOfuser.clear();
                      messageOfuser.clear();
                    });
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("FeedbackMessages")
                        .add(data);
                  }: null
)
```

Comment: I would like to ask if you need to create a new dart file just for the form questionnaire? or you can just create it to the feedbackpage dart?

Comment: actually in your case  separate your widgets into separated file would helps to read your code better. @Giotto

Comment: Yeah, I also would like to do that but I am new to flutter, to be honest with you Ahah. I am trying to make reusable widgets also but I don't know how. Maybe I will also ask about that because the tutorials on youtube are outdated.

Comment: I might also ask because the Flutter TensorFlow version is deprecated to the new dart language.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

   class SimpleDialog extends StatelessWidget {
   // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
   final title;

   const SimpleDialog(this.title, {super.key});

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Alert'),
      content: Text(title),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: const Text('OK'))
      ],
    );
  }
}

class FeedbackPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FeedbackPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<FeedbackPage> createState() => _FeedbackPageState();
}

class _FeedbackPageState extends State<FeedbackPage> {
  final nameOfuser = TextEditingController();
  final emailOfuser = TextEditingController();
  final messageOfuser = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  List<bool> isTypeSelected = [false, false, false, true, true];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        // AppBar para sa taas ng design
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            "PicLeaf",
            style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 102, 1.0), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          shadowColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 95, 94, 94),
        ),

        //body of the application
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffeeeeee),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              const Text(
                "Feedback",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontFamily: 'RobotoBold', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 102, 1.0)),
              ),
              const Text(
                "Give us your feedback!",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium',
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: nameOfuser,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          hintText: "Name",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                        validator: (nameOfuser) {
                          if (nameOfuser == null || nameOfuser.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter your Name';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: emailOfuser,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          hintText: "Email",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                        validator: (emailOfuser) {
                          if (emailOfuser == null || emailOfuser.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter your Email';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: messageOfuser,
                        maxLines: 6,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          hintText: "Message",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                        validator: (messageOfuser) {
                          if (messageOfuser == null || messageOfuser.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please enter your Message';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      MaterialButton(
                        height: 50.0,
                        minWidth: double.infinity,
                        color: const Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 102, 1.0),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                  return const SimpleDialog('Feedback Submitted');
                                });
                            Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                              "Name": nameOfuser.text,
                              "Email": emailOfuser.text,
                              "Message": messageOfuser.text,
                              "Time": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                            };
                            setState(() {
                              nameOfuser.clear();
                              emailOfuser.clear();
                              messageOfuser.clear();
                            });
                            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("FeedbackMessages").add(data);
                          }
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          "SUBMIT",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'RobotoBold',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 10),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Contact Us!',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontFamily: 'RobotoBold', color: Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 102, 1.0)),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                            child: TextButton.icon(
                              // <-- TextButton
                              onPressed: () {},
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.facebook,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                size: 35.0,
                              ),
                              label: const Text(
                                'facebook.com/picleaf',
                                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium'),
                              ),
                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 10),
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                              child: TextButton.icon(
                                // <-- TextButton
                                onPressed: () {},
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.email,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  size: 35.0,
                                ),

                                label: const Text(
                                  'picleaf@gmail.com',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium'),
                                ),

                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                  foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

You can replace this code with your code.
here i am using Form widget with _formKey

Comment: I manage to do the application but  I would like to ask how can you create a validation with letters and @ for emails? thank you for the response.